# Sum of last X days for when "day" <= X

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr::lag`, I can easily calculate the sum of the last n values of a field over time. A problem occurs, however, for the first n rows of the calculated field. An example of taking the sum of the prior 4 days for each day:

```
# Load dplyr
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame
day <- 1:7
set.seed(123)
value <- round(rnorm(7,20,10))
df <- data.frame(day,value)

# Function to sum last i values of column x (using dplyr::lag)
rollag <- function(x, i){
  lagsum = 0
  for(u in 1:i){
    lagsum = lagsum + lag(x,u)
  }
  lagsum
}

# Create column for sum of last 4 values of `value`
dfm <- mutate(df, Last4 = rollag(value,4))
```

This creates the following table `dfm`:

```
   day value Last4
1    1    14    NA
2    2    18    NA
3    3    36    NA
4    4    21    NA
5    5    21    89
6    6    37    96
7    7    25   115
```

As you can see, the code is correctly calculating the prior 4 values for all days > 4. What I want is for days 2,3,4 to be the sum of the prior 1,2,3 days so that all rows have a value filled in except for 1 (since there are no values prior to day 1). I can update each value by doing `dfm$Last4[4] = rollag(dfm$value,3)[4]` but would be tedious.

I'd prefer to make any changes in the `rollag` function, since I use this function a ton throughout my project. If a solution exists in `rollag`, then it will flow throughout the project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you change `lagsum = lagsum + lag(x,u,default=0)` in the `rollag` function, it solves the problem for `i=2,3,4`, and there will be a 0 for `i=1`. If you want you can replace it by NA.

Comment: @Masoud This modified `rollag` function when called on `df$value` returns 0  14  32  68  89  96 115, which I think is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Lamia Works perfectly and very simple. Thanks so much for your help!