# Trying to calculate a conditional rolling cumulative count by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate a count of days by group within a rolling five day window using data.table. Sample code and input:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

DT <- structure(list(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    date = structure(c(16740, 16790, 16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 16815, 16961, 16962, 16963
  ), class = "Date")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  .Names = c("id", "date")) %>% 
  as.data.table()
```

```
id       date
 1:  1 2015-11-01
 2:  1 2015-12-21
 3:  1 2015-12-22
 4:  1 2015-12-23
 5:  1 2015-12-24
 6:  1 2015-12-25
 7:  2 2016-01-15
 8:  2 2016-06-09
 9:  2 2016-06-10
10:  2 2016-06-11
```

But I'm at a loss of how to do so. I know you can do cumulative sum by group using

```
DT[, cumsum := cumsum(.N), by = .(id)]
```

, but how can I make it a rolling sum conditional on date? What I'm looking for is this, where the count is rolling and limited to include records within the last five days:

```
      id date       count
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1 2015-11-01     1
 2     1 2015-12-21     1
 3     1 2015-12-22     2
 4     1 2015-12-23     3
 5     1 2015-12-24     4
 6     1 2015-12-25     5
 7     2 2016-01-15     1
 8     2 2016-06-09     1
 9     2 2016-06-10     2
10     2 2016-06-11     3
```

Comment: CHeck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960352/optimized-rolling-functions-on-irregular-time-series-with-time-based-window

Comment: Additionally, you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314594/sum-of-last-x-days-for-when-day-x

Comment: In particular, you can do `DT[, N := DT[.(d_dn = date - 5, d_up = date), on=.(date >= d_dn, date <= d_up), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]`

Comment: Frank's solution works like a charm. Thanks!